# Python Variable scope with a function as a parameter

Tags: python, scope

```
def fvals_sqrt(x):
   """
   Return f(x) and f'(x) for applying Newton to find a square root.
   """
   f = x**2 - 4.
   fp = 2.*x
   return f, fp

def solve(fvals_sqrt, x0, debug_solve=True):
   """
   Solves the sqrt function, using newtons methon.
   """
   fvals_sqrt(x0)
   x0 = x0 + (f/fp)
   print x0
```

When I try to call the function solve, python returns:

```
NameError: global name 'f' is not defined
```

Obviously this is a scope issue, but how can I use f within my solve function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
def solve(fvals_sqrt, x0, debug_solve=True):
    """
    Solves the sqrt function, using newtons methon.
    """
    f, fp = fvals_sqrt(x0) # Get the return values from fvals_sqrt
    x0 = x0 + (f/fp)
    print x0
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `fvals_sqrt()` but don't do anything with the return values, so they are discarded.  Returning variables won't magically make them exist inside the calling function. Your call should be like so:

```
f, fp = fvals_sqrt(x0)
```

Of course, you don't need to use the same names for the variables as are used in the `return` statement of the function you're calling.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that you're not storing the returned value from the function call anywhere:

```
f,fp = fvals_sqrt(x0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unfold result of `fvals_sqrt(x0)`, with this line

```
f, fp = fvals_sqrt(x0)
```

Globally, you should try

```
def fvals_sqrt(x):
   """
   Return f(x) and f'(x) for applying Newton to find a square root.
   """
   f = x**2 - 4.
   fp = 2.*x
   return f, fp

def solve(x0, debug_solve=True):
   """
   Solves the sqrt function, using newtons methon.
   """
   f, fp = fvals_sqrt(x0)
   x0 = x0 + (f/fp)
   print x0

solve(3)
```

Result

```
>>> 
3.83333333333
```